# Trouble passing data through res.locals in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to pass my route information to every views. I need to use `req.path` variable inside my `index.ejs`. So I tried to pass the data through `res.locals`, but it's not working.

My app.js

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.path = req.path;
  next();
});

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.render('classes/index');
});
```

index.ejs

```
<% if(!path=='/'){ %>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Log In</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Sign Up</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
<% } %>
```

Anyone see where I screwed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middleware to set `res.locals` should come before creating `router` instance:

```
const router = require('express').Router();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.path = req.path;
  next();
});

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.render('classes/index');
});

app.use(router);
```

Comment: Yeah! but I need path variable in every views. I'm trying to make my code dry as possible

Comment: Will req.path be dynamic, or the same for each request?

Comment: Dynamic I guess

Comment: Also can you show where are you creating the router, before or after the middleware?

Comment: Thanks, my middleware was placed after the routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data like this:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.render('classes/index', {path: req.path});
});
```

Comment: This is a possible workaround (which is, IMHO, much better than relying on res.locals), but not really an answer. res.render merges the params you give it with the key-value pairs from res.locals. But for some routing reason res.locals never gets populated with 'path' key.